# Get count of rows and a flag depending on some column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table with 4 columns:

```
id,familyId,memberType,memberName
=================================
1,     1,     main,      RBV
2,     1,     spouse,    VBD
3,     1,     child,     CDE
4,     2,     spouse,    OLL
5,     2,     sibling,   HAQ
6,     3,     main,      OOM
7,     3,     sibling,   NBB
8,     3,     child,     SSS
```

Using this data, how can I write a query to get the count of members in each family and whether the family has main?

This is what I need :

```
familyId,count,hasMain
=====================
1,     3,     1
2,     2,     0
3,     3,     1
```

I know `group by familyId` will give me the count of members in each family. But it does not give me whether the family has main in it. Perhaps this cannot be acheived in a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use aggregate function `COUNT()` to count all rows based from `familyID` and `MAX()` with `CASE` statement to check if `membertype` column has *main*:

```
SELECT  familyID,
        COUNT(*) AS "Count",
        MAX(CASE WHEN memberType = 'main' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS hasMain
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY familyID
```

Comment: Saved an entire day for me .. Thanks John Woo

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation along with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    familyId,
    COUNT(*) AS family_cnt,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN memberType = 'main' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS hasMain
FROM
    yourTable
GROUP BY
    familyId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do that:

```
SQL> with test (id, familyid, membertype) as
  2    (select 1, 1, 'main'    from dual union
  3     select 2, 1, 'spouse'  from dual union
  4     select 3, 1, 'child'   from dual union
  5     select 4, 2, 'spouse'  from dual union
  6     select 5, 2, 'sibling' from dual union
  7     select 6, 3, 'main'    from dual union
  8     select 7, 3, 'sibling' from dual union
  9     select 8, 3, 'child'   from dual
 10    ),
 11  hm as
 12    (select familyid
 13     from test
 14     where membertype = 'main'
 15    )
 16  select t.familyid,
 17         count(*) cnt,
 18         decode(hm.familyid, null, 0, 1) hasmain
 19  from test t
 20  left join hm on hm.familyid = t.familyid
 21  group by t.familyid, decode(hm.familyid, null, 0, 1)
 22  order by t.familyid;

  FAMILYID        CNT    HASMAIN
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3          1
         2          2          0
         3          3          1

SQL>
```

Comment: This is not a good line of attack. As the other two Answers demonstrate, the output can be obtained in a single aggregate query; no need to read the base table twice and to join the results of two different row sets.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that; thank you, @mathguy. It is not the *best*, most probably even *right* way to do it, but it shows yet another possible way to get the result. I agree, John & TIm posted much better solutions.

Comment: They were also posted a few minutes before you posted yours. In such cases, you have the option of NOT posting your answer (which adds nothing to what has already been posted). It adds no value to show a different, but inferior, method of solving the same requirement.

Comment: Right; I should have refreshed the page, didn't even notice that two other answers have already been posted.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this,

```
SELECT familyid, count(1) count_, MAX(DECODE(membertype, 'main', 1, 0)) has_main
  FROM test
 GROUP BY familyid;
```